# Is a Socket.IO socket ID sensitive/private data?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

When a new connection is handled by Socket.IO, it creates a `Socket` object, and one of this object's properties is `id`. This is an "unguessable" (according to the documentation) string used to identify the connection.

When building applications, is it considered safe, secure and good practice to broadcast this ID to other clients? My inclination is that hashing the ID and broadcasting the digest may be a better idea.

Comment: It isn't related to anything, it's as good as a newly created hash in itself. Why are you broadcasting it to others anyway?

Comment: @laggingreflex I'm broadcasting it simply as a way to identify other clients. It's a very simple game-like app, and clients broadcast X and Y positions. Objects containing the other clients' coordinates are created, and frequently updated. I need a way to name these objects, and I'm currently using the IDs generated by Socket.IO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The id is not sensitive data unless your own code somehow makes it sensitive.  There are no socket.io client operations that take the socket id, so if a client has a socket id, there is nothing they can do with it unless your code implements message that operate on it.

It is unguessable so that you can use it as an id to share with other clients while not allowing that client to know who's id they might have been given (like an anonymous id).

So, using it as an identifier to refer to some other user's socket is exactly what it was intended for and does not cause a security or privacy issue unless your own client operations cause such.

Comment: I see, thank-you. It seems this is the case so I'll accept your answer.